# Simultaneous application execution

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-ael

Hello guys,

I would like help to setting up my dial plan to execute more than one application at a time. In the example below I created 3 contexts, where the call made by the anlz01 context makes a dial to the anlz02 context and makes a subroutine for the anlz03 context.

The following example context:

```
context anlz01 {
    _X. => {
        Dial(local/200@anlz03,30,CU(anlz02,s,1));
    }
}

context anlz02 {
    200 => {
        Playback(gravacoes/21971192789-20170103-143043-P1C55-E1, noanswer);
    }
}

context anlz03 {
    s => {
        Wait(3);
        Progress();
        Wait(5);
        Hangup();
    }
}
```

My goal is that while the playback is running the other applications of the anlz03 context also has be executed. How could I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

It is not fully clear what exactly you need.

Asterisk dialplan allow execute ONE application stream.

If you need same time playback something, create other channel set using asterisk dialout, after that use ChanSpy app to wisper that to first channel.

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+ChanSpy

If you need execution of some complex math, use FastAGI and your favorite language with Threads.

You also have option supply hold music to be played while you are dialling. See application Dial parameters.